# sql join query to get most viewed atricles by country

Tags: mysql, sql, join

having a hard time pulling articles based on user country views

i have the following tables with their fields

```
user: id, country_id
article: id
article_views: id, user_id, article_id
```

each time a user views an article I insert it into the article_views table, like this:

```
article_views.id   article_id   user_id
2                  1            1   
3                  2            1   
4                  2            2   
5                  2            2
```

I want to pull the highest viewed article for current user.country_id. I imagine it will contain:

```
order by article_views.article_id DESC
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: oh sorry it's the primary key, auto incremented, i will edit the question

Comment: Do you mean 'most viewed article' or 'the article with the highest id'?

Comment: @Strawberry the most viewed, where it has the highest number of users who viewed it

Comment: Highest number of DISTINCT users?

Comment: doesn't really matter, just any user, it can be abused by one user but not really a problem for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select av.id, count(*) as views
from article_views av inner join user u on av.user_id = u.id
where u.country_id = 'cc'
group by u.country_id
order by views desc;
```

Comment: even though it looks alright, I get
`article_id 1 with 9 views`

like it is summing all views into this one article. article 1 has only 3 views...

Comment: I just got it to work, changed the group by to `article_views.article_id`
thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This should work fine:

```
select article_id, count(*) as views
from article_views inner join user on article_views.user_id = user.id
group by user.country_id
order by views desc;
```

Edit. I forgot about grouping article_id as @Josien pointed, the correct query is:

```
select country_id, article_id, count(*) as views
from article_views inner join user on article_views.user_id = user.id
where country_id = ':countryID'
group by user.country_id, article_id
order by views desc;
```

Comment: even though it looks alright, I get
`article_id 1 with 9 views`

like it is summing all views into this one article. article 1 has only 3 views...

Comment: I think you should GROUP on article_id as well. Otherwise it will dump all article_views in the same group, as @Amin says.

Comment: thanksss @Josien, i just got it to work, as you said changed the group by to article_views.article_id thanks all!